# Символ "$" в JavaScripty. JQuery. Как расшифровать код?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, помогите понять код, я не изучал нигде js и прочее.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Проверка корректности введенных данных
function validateData(){
    var errors = new Array();
    if( $('input[name="email"]').val() == '' ){
        errors.push( 'Поле "Эл. почта" не может быть пустым' );
    }
    if( $('input[name="password-first"]' ).val() == '' ){
        errors.push( 'Поле "Пароль" не может быть пустым' );
    }
    if( $('input[name="password-second"]').val() == '' ){
        errors.push( 'Поле "Подветржение пароля" не может быть пустым' );
    }
    if( $('input[name="password-second"]').val() != $('input[name="password-first"]' ).val() ){
        errors.push( '"Пароль" и "Подветржение пароля" должны совпадать' );
    }
    if( $('input[name="name"]').val() == '' ){
        errors.push( 'Поле "Имя" не может быть пустым' );
    }
    if( errors.length > 0 ){
        var message = "Внимание:\n";
        message += errors.join("\n");
        alert( message );
        return false;
    }
    return true;                
}

/**
* Отправка формы при нажатии кнопки "Зарегестрировать" 
*/
$('#register').click(function(){
    if( validateData() ){   
        $('#employer-registration').submit();
        dataLayer.push({'registration_employer': 'registration_employer_success'});
    }
}); 
});
```

такой вот код. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при успешной! отправке данных заполненной формы на сервер передавался так же уровень данных `datalayer`

```
dataLayer.push({'registration_employer': 'registration_employer_success'});
```

Извиняюсь за глупые вопросы. Хелп. Спасибо.

Comment: Кривой какой-то получился вопрос. Суть вопроса в том, что правильно ли я прописал уровень данных?
Скажите пожалуйста код: $('#register') что обозначает в jQuery? Это ссылка на другой файл?

Comment: Это селектор элемента c `id='register'`. Почитайте про селекторы в jQuery

Comment: *я не изучал нигде js и прочее* - может быть стоит начать если хотите на нем написать код? и многие вопросы сразу исчезнут...

Comment: > я не изучал нигде js и прочее - вам тогда сначала стоит изучить его, а потом уже задавать вопросы

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, прочитал, понял что к чему примерно. Ребят, я не кодю, у меня другая работа, просто резко понадобилось разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это скорее всего вам нужно писать не в этом участке кода, который вы прислали. А в том, где у вас собираются данные с полей и отправляются методом POST. Туда нужно положить свой массив `dataLayer`.

В вашем случае код, который отправляет что-то на сервер выглядеть должен как-то так (или содержит как минимум такой запрос):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

В параметре `data` лежит массив или объект, или JSON, или просто строка, которая отправляет данные с полей.

Нужно либо к этой строке присоединить свой `dataLayer`, либо написать подобный запрос и отправить `dataLayer` отдельно.

Comment: Благодарочка!!!

Comment: Встречный вопрос возник, нет ли случайно какого-то простого расширения для Chrome в целях поисках таких файлов, которые отправляют данные.

Comment: @АлександрМишура вам нужно просто писать console.log(здесь ваши переменные или еще что-то, что отправляете на сервер) и вы увидите все в инструментах разработчика в браузере.

Comment: @АлександрМишура а если вам нужно красивое отображение JSON в браузере, то вот расширение: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: @АлександрМишура если вы желаете проверить отправку или что-то подобное, то можете использовать вот это: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: Перерыл все файлы, нашёл те которые похожи на тот файл, который отправляет, но они все не о том, они другие какие-то емейл отправляют или что-то ещё, нет другого способа выявить файлы такие?
postman это вообще программа какая-то, не разобрался пока.